# The Python script youtube-dl returns a new file

Tags: python, youtube, download

I'm writing a script which uses [youtube-dl](http://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl/) in a subprocess, `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)`, to download a YouTube video. What is the best way to get back the new file (which is determined by `%(title)s.%(ext)s` variables by youtube-dl `--output=TEMPLATE`)?

Unfortunately, there is no option to print the new file name which I could redirect to a variable. I could check for the latest created file in the download directory, but that feels unsafe, as I'll be using the information for other commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does print destination filenane on stdout. It looks like this:
`[download] Destination: XXX`
if you give it options `--no-progress --output=XXX`.

Or you could make a template for filename that would allow you to easily recognize newly downloaded file: `%(title)s.%(ext)s-latest-download` or something and rename it later.